# CCParallaxNode adding childs while scrolling

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'am using a CCParallaxNode to scroll 3 backgrounds along with Ray Wenderlich's category to move the backgrounds when they go out of the screen.

It is working just fine, my problem is that i want to add childs (enimies) on the fly, like every 5 seconds. Normally i would just add the enemies to the parent layer using a CCMoveTo action to animate him over the screen but I want my enimies to follow the foreground of the parallax layer.

I'am increasing the scroll speed slowly as the game progresses.

I can't seem to figure out the right offset when calling

```
CGFloat offset = self.gameBackground.position.x;
[self.gameBackground addChild:enimy z:5 parallaxRatio:ccp(0.1, 0.1) positionOffset:ccp(offset, 85)];
```

Can someone help me out with this?

edit:

I'am doing this to move the background:

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)delta
{
    self.speed -= 0.5f;
    CGPoint backgroundScrollVel = ccp(self.speed, 0);
    self.gameBackground.position = ccpAdd(self.gameBackground.position, ccpMult(backgroundScrollVel, delta));
}
```

Thanks

Rays article: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3611/how-to-make-a-space-shooter-iphone-game

**Final solution:**

I ended up just adding the enimies to the CCLayer instead of the Parallax. To move the enimies in the same speed as the foremost layer child in Parallax i did the following:

in update:(ccTime)delta:

```
CGFloat parallaxRatio = 0.1f;
CGPoint backgroundScrollVel = ccp((self.backgroundSpeed * - 1) * parallaxRatio, 0);
for(WKEnimy *enemy in self.enimies)
{
    enemy.position = ccpAdd(enemy.position, ccpMult(backgroundScrollVel, delta));
}
```

Comment: Is `gameBackground` the `ParallaxNode` or one of its childs?

Comment: gameBackground is a ParallaxNode

Comment: In that case, wouldn't it be easier to add your enemy sprites to one of the child layers (actually, the layer that holds your main character Sprite)?

Comment: Yeah it would. But i need the enemy to scroll at same speed as the front most layer of the ParallaxNode.

Comment: Mm I see, but then you still need to add your enemies to that layer, not to Parallax.

Comment: well.. then how would i go about calculating the duration for a CCMoveTo action :o

Comment: I just post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add your enemy `CCSprites` to your foreground `CCLayer` (instead of directly adding them to your `CCParallaxNode`). Besides, I wouldn't recommend using actions (such as `CCMoveTo`) for this particular case; you may update your sprites positions as your doing with your `gameBackground`, and 'manually' check wether or not they're off the screen.

Comment: This is actually what i already got but i'am using CCMoveTo to move it across the screen. How would i move it otherwise?

Comment: You would move it the same way you're moving `gameBackground`. Off the top of my head, it would something like enemy.position = ccp(enemy.position.x - offset, enemy.position.y) for horizontal movement.

Comment: Glad you finally made it :)